# How to merge several TS files to one with correct timestamps?

Tags: mpeg2-ts

How to merge several TS files file to one TS file with correct timestamps?
I can just merge the files to one without touching data. This will produce a playable file, but with incorrect timestamps, so timeline will not be shown (in VLC for example). So I need to recalculate timestamps, somehow using gstreamer/ffmpeg or any command line tool for that and possibly prevent unnecessary reencoding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about [PTS/DTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6044365/3194340) that you might have to [tweak](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html):

- Check `setpts` and `asetpts` from [ffmpeg doc](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts)
- An example of how to use it in this [related question](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/10401)