# How to record windows screen with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, record

I want to write application that could recording screen as a video in **c++**

During the search I found ffmpeg can done that.

What examples should I use to create a program?

I use the window api

I can load bitmaps into memory.

---

What I want to do is:

1. Loads 30 bitmaps in memory in one second.
2. Generate video using multiple bitmaps.

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question - continue your search for examples/tutorials.

Comment: Thank you I found out what was missing from my question.

Comment: a c++ program to capture the screen and store it in mp4 format github link https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp and http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43464269/6180077 visit this link for working FFMPEG c++ mp4 format screen recorder application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg can record screen with code like:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" output.flv
```

please check [ffmpeg document](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) for full help.

If you can capture picture from screen please see [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511312/how-to-encode-a-video-from-several-images-generated-in-a-c-program-without-wri)

Comment: Thank you for answer                                                                           

But I use the window api

I can load bitmaps into memory.

What I want to do is:

1. Loads 30 bitmaps in memory in one second.

2. Generate video using multiple bitmaps.

Comment: you indeed want to capture screen by your program in memory and then create video from that?

Comment: @Soer: Then why did you ask for something different?

Comment: @MikeMB  I couldn't express myself properly about my problem.

Comment: @combo_ci  That’s right.   Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Soer now the question is different...please folow the link in answer...a complete answer exist in that link that done everything you want with ffmpeg

Comment: @combo_ci  Thank you. 
I will learn from the example.