# C++ FFmpeg create mp4 file

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm trying to create mp4 video file with FFmpeg and C++, but in result I receive broken file (windows player shows "Can't play ... 0xc00d36c4"). If I create .h264 file, it can be played with 'ffplay' and successfully converted to mp4 via CL.

My code:

```
int main() {
    char *filename = "tmp.mp4";
    AVOutputFormat *fmt;
    AVFormatContext *fctx;
    AVCodecContext *cctx;
    AVStream *st;

    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    //auto detect the output format from the name
    fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);
    if (!fmt) {
        cout << "Error av_guess_format()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }

    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fctx, fmt, NULL, filename) < 0) {
        cout << "Error avformat_alloc_output_context2()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }


    //stream creation + parameters
    st = avformat_new_stream(fctx, 0);
    if (!st) {
        cout << "Error avformat_new_stream()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }

    st->codecpar->codec_id = fmt->video_codec;
    st->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    st->codecpar->width = 352;
    st->codecpar->height = 288;
    st->time_base.num = 1;
    st->time_base.den = 25;

    AVCodec *pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(st->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!pCodec) {
        cout << "Error avcodec_find_encoder()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }

    cctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    if (!cctx) {
        cout << "Error avcodec_alloc_context3()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(cctx, st->codecpar);
    cctx->bit_rate = 400000;
    cctx->width = 352;
    cctx->height = 288;
    cctx->time_base.num = 1;
    cctx->time_base.den = 25;
    cctx->gop_size = 12;
    cctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (st->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
        av_opt_set(cctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }
    if (fctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(st->codecpar, cctx);

    av_dump_format(fctx, 0, filename, 1);

    //OPEN FILE + WRITE HEADER
    if (avcodec_open2(cctx, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        cout << "Error avcodec_open2()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&fctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            cout << "Error avio_open()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
        }
    }
    if (avformat_write_header(fctx, NULL) < 0) {
        cout << "Error avformat_write_header()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }


    //CREATE DUMMY VIDEO
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    frame->format = cctx->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = cctx->width;
    frame->height = cctx->height;
    av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, cctx->width, cctx->height, cctx->pix_fmt, 32);

    AVPacket pkt;
    double video_pts = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        video_pts = (double)cctx->time_base.num / cctx->time_base.den * 90 * i;

        for (int y = 0; y < cctx->height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cctx->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
                if (y < cctx->height / 2 && x < cctx->width / 2) {
                    /* Cb and Cr */
                    frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                    frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
                }
            }
        }

        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        pkt.pts = frame->pts = video_pts;
        pkt.data = NULL;
        pkt.size = 0;
        pkt.stream_index = st->index;

        if (avcodec_send_frame(cctx, frame) < 0) {
            cout << "Error avcodec_send_frame()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
        }
        if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
            //cout << "Write frame " << to_string((int) pkt.pts) << endl;
            av_interleaved_write_frame(fctx, &pkt);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
    }

    //DELAYED FRAMES
    for (;;) {
        avcodec_send_frame(cctx, NULL);
        if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
            //cout << "-Write frame " << to_string((int)pkt.pts) << endl;
            av_interleaved_write_frame(fctx, &pkt);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    //FINISH
    av_write_trailer(fctx);
    if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_close(fctx->pb) < 0) {
            cout << "Error avio_close()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
        }
    }
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    avcodec_free_context(&cctx);
    avformat_free_context(fctx);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output of program:

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp.mp4':
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 352x288, q=2-31, 400 kb/s, 25 tbn
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 2.0
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] 264 - core 152 r2851 ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=12 keyint_min=1 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=400 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] frame I:5     Avg QP: 7.03  size:  9318
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] frame P:45    Avg QP: 4.53  size:  4258
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] final ratefactor: 9.11
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 18.9% 21.8% 14.5% inter: 7.8% 100.0% 15.5%
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  4%  5%  5% 86%
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] i8c dc,h,v,p:  2%  9%  6% 82%
[libx264 @ 0000021c4a995ba0] kb/s:264.68
```

If I will try to play mp4 file with 'ffplay' it prints:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000026bf900] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 352x288, 138953 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
[h264 @ 00000000006c6ae0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 00000000006c6ae0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000006c6ae0] no frame!
```

I've spent a lot of time without success of finding issue, what could be the reason of it?

Thank for help!

Comment: How did you finally fix the code?

Comment: @ar2015 Look at the answer, I've posted my solution. Looks like it couldn't write directly to mp4 container, so I created h264 first, and then remuxed into mp4.

Comment: Minimal working example at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831761/how-to-resize-a-picture-using-ffmpegs-sws-scale/36487785#36487785

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The current solution is wrong. It's a workaround at best. It encodes the video into h264 first and then remuxes it into mp4. This is not necessary.

The true solution is removing:

cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

This is my full solution:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libavutil/avutil.h>
    #include <libavutil/time.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

AVFrame* videoFrame = nullptr;
AVCodecContext* cctx = nullptr;
SwsContext* swsCtx = nullptr;
int frameCounter = 0;
AVFormatContext* ofctx = nullptr;
AVOutputFormat* oformat = nullptr;
int fps = 30;
int width = 1920;
int height = 1080;
int bitrate = 2000;

static void pushFrame(uint8_t* data) {
    int err;
    if (!videoFrame) {
        videoFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        videoFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        videoFrame->width = cctx->width;
        videoFrame->height = cctx->height;
        if ((err = av_frame_get_buffer(videoFrame, 32)) < 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to allocate picture" << err << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (!swsCtx) {
        swsCtx = sws_getContext(cctx->width, cctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, cctx->width, 
            cctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    int inLinesize[1] = { 3 * cctx->width };
    // From RGB to YUV
    sws_scale(swsCtx, (const uint8_t* const*)&data, inLinesize, 0, cctx->height, 
        videoFrame->data, videoFrame->linesize);
    videoFrame->pts = (1.0 / 30.0) * 90000 * (frameCounter++);
    std::cout << videoFrame->pts << " " << cctx->time_base.num << " " << 
        cctx->time_base.den << " " << frameCounter << std::endl;
    if ((err = avcodec_send_frame(cctx, videoFrame)) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to send frame" << err << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    AV_TIME_BASE;
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;
    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
        static int counter = 0;
        if (counter == 0) {
            FILE* fp = fopen("dump_first_frame1.dat", "wb");
            fwrite(pkt.data, pkt.size, 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
        }
        std::cout << "pkt key: " << (pkt.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) << " " << 
            pkt.size << " " << (counter++) << std::endl;
        uint8_t* size = ((uint8_t*)pkt.data);
        std::cout << "first: " << (int)size[0] << " " << (int)size[1] << 
            " " << (int)size[2] << " " << (int)size[3] << " " << (int)size[4] << 
            " " << (int)size[5] << " " << (int)size[6] << " " << (int)size[7] << 
            std::endl;
        av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, &pkt);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
}

static void finish() {
    //DELAYED FRAMES
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    for (;;) {
        avcodec_send_frame(cctx, NULL);
        if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
            av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, &pkt);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofctx);
    if (!(oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        int err = avio_close(ofctx->pb);
        if (err < 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to close file" << err << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

static void free() {
    if (videoFrame) {
        av_frame_free(&videoFrame);
    }
    if (cctx) {
        avcodec_free_context(&cctx);
    }
    if (ofctx) {
        avformat_free_context(ofctx);
    }
    if (swsCtx) {
        sws_freeContext(swsCtx);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    oformat = av_guess_format(nullptr, "test.mp4", nullptr);
    if (!oformat)
    {
        std::cout << "can't create output format" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    //oformat->video_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_H265;

    int err = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofctx, oformat, nullptr, "test.mp4");

    if (err)
    {
        std::cout << "can't create output context" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    AVCodec* codec = nullptr;

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(oformat->video_codec);
    if (!codec)
    {
        std::cout << "can't create codec" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(ofctx, codec);

    if (!stream)
    {
        std::cout << "can't find format" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

    if (!cctx)
    {
        std::cout << "can't create codec context" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    stream->codecpar->codec_id = oformat->video_codec;
    stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    stream->codecpar->width = width;
    stream->codecpar->height = height;
    stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    stream->codecpar->bit_rate = bitrate * 1000;
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(cctx, stream->codecpar);
    cctx->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, 1 };
    cctx->max_b_frames = 2;
    cctx->gop_size = 12;
    cctx->framerate = (AVRational){ fps, 1 };
    //must remove the following
    //cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
        av_opt_set(cctx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }
    else if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H265)
    {
        av_opt_set(cctx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, cctx);

    if ((err = avcodec_open2(cctx, codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open codec" << err << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if ((err = avio_open(&ofctx->pb, "test.mp4", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to open file" << err << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    if ((err = avformat_write_header(ofctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to write header" << err << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    av_dump_format(ofctx, 0, "test.mp4", 1);

    uint8_t* frameraw = new uint8_t[1920 * 1080 * 4];
    memset(frameraw, 222, 1920 * 1080 * 4);
    for (int i = 0;i < 60;++i) {
        pushFrame(frameraw);
    }

    delete[] frameraw;
    finish();
    free();
    return 0;
}
```

here is how I debugged the issue:

I started with the questioner's solution first. I compared the packets generated by encoding and by remuxing,

during the first encoding the first packet misses a header:

[image]

When remuxing, the first packet has a header:

[image]

I then noticed AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER. judging by its name, it seems to write a global header and strip the packet header.

So I removed it, and everything worked. I have detailed my discovery [here](https://epiphany.pub/@shi-yan/hahwhw).

code is here with makefile： https://github.com/shi-yan/videosamples

Comment: This answer has helpful info for setting the correct DTS values using av_packet_rescale_ts(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511312/how-to-encode-a-video-from-several-images-generated-in-a-c-program-without-wri#answer-34688916

Comment: This does not work. When I debug it it is stuck on if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0)

Comment: Have been looking for this kind of stuff for a few hours as almost there's no updated example on the internet. Although this is the most compatible one with ffmpeg's last version, I had to alter it a bit this way:
https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#bavalwrrbzkra0ht4domw

Comment: This solution not working on Android. The created mp4 file can't open. Also i tried the openCV solutions but nothing will worked. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Working solution:

```
#include "VideoCapture.h"

#define VIDEO_TMP_FILE "tmp.h264"
#define FINAL_FILE_NAME "record.mp4"


using namespace std;

void VideoCapture::Init(int width, int height, int fpsrate, int bitrate) {

    fps = fpsrate;

    int err;

    if (!(oformat = av_guess_format(NULL, VIDEO_TMP_FILE, NULL))) {
        Debug("Failed to define output format", 0);
        return;
    }

    if ((err = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofctx, oformat, NULL, VIDEO_TMP_FILE) < 0)) {
        Debug("Failed to allocate output context", err);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    if (!(codec = avcodec_find_encoder(oformat->video_codec))) {
        Debug("Failed to find encoder", 0);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    if (!(videoStream = avformat_new_stream(ofctx, codec))) {
        Debug("Failed to create new stream", 0);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    if (!(cctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec))) {
        Debug("Failed to allocate codec context", 0);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    videoStream->codecpar->codec_id = oformat->video_codec;
    videoStream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    videoStream->codecpar->width = width;
    videoStream->codecpar->height = height;
    videoStream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    videoStream->codecpar->bit_rate = bitrate * 1000;
    videoStream->time_base = { 1, fps };

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(cctx, videoStream->codecpar);
    cctx->time_base = { 1, fps };
    cctx->max_b_frames = 2;
    cctx->gop_size = 12;
    if (videoStream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
        av_opt_set(cctx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }
    if (ofctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(videoStream->codecpar, cctx);

    if ((err = avcodec_open2(cctx, codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to open codec", err);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    if (!(oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if ((err = avio_open(&ofctx->pb, VIDEO_TMP_FILE, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0) {
            Debug("Failed to open file", err);
            Free();
            return;
        }
    }

    if ((err = avformat_write_header(ofctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to write header", err);
        Free();
        return;
    }

    av_dump_format(ofctx, 0, VIDEO_TMP_FILE, 1);
}

void VideoCapture::AddFrame(uint8_t *data) {
    int err;
    if (!videoFrame) {

        videoFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        videoFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        videoFrame->width = cctx->width;
        videoFrame->height = cctx->height;

        if ((err = av_frame_get_buffer(videoFrame, 32)) < 0) {
            Debug("Failed to allocate picture", err);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!swsCtx) {
        swsCtx = sws_getContext(cctx->width, cctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, cctx->width, cctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_BICUBIC, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    int inLinesize[1] = { 3 * cctx->width };

    // From RGB to YUV
    sws_scale(swsCtx, (const uint8_t * const *)&data, inLinesize, 0, cctx->height, videoFrame->data, videoFrame->linesize);

    videoFrame->pts = frameCounter++;

    if ((err = avcodec_send_frame(cctx, videoFrame)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to send frame", err);
        return;
    }

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, &pkt);
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
}

void VideoCapture::Finish() {
    //DELAYED FRAMES
    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    for (;;) {
        avcodec_send_frame(cctx, NULL);
        if (avcodec_receive_packet(cctx, &pkt) == 0) {
            av_interleaved_write_frame(ofctx, &pkt);
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofctx);
    if (!(oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        int err = avio_close(ofctx->pb);
        if (err < 0) {
            Debug("Failed to close file", err);
        }
    }

    Free();

    Remux();
}

void VideoCapture::Free() {
    if (videoFrame) {
        av_frame_free(&videoFrame);
    }
    if (cctx) {
        avcodec_free_context(&cctx);
    }
    if (ofctx) {
        avformat_free_context(ofctx);
    }
    if (swsCtx) {
        sws_freeContext(swsCtx);
    }
}

void VideoCapture::Remux() {
    AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx = NULL, *ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    int err;

    if ((err = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, VIDEO_TMP_FILE, 0, 0)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to open input file for remuxing", err);
        goto end;
    }
    if ((err = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to retrieve input stream information", err);
        goto end;
    }
    if ((err = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, FINAL_FILE_NAME))) {
        Debug("Failed to allocate output context", err);
        goto end;
    }

    AVStream *inVideoStream = ifmt_ctx->streams[0];
    AVStream *outVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (!outVideoStream) {
        Debug("Failed to allocate output video stream", 0);
        goto end;
    }
    outVideoStream->time_base = { 1, fps };
    avcodec_parameters_copy(outVideoStream->codecpar, inVideoStream->codecpar);
    outVideoStream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if ((err = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, FINAL_FILE_NAME, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0) {
            Debug("Failed to open output file", err);
            goto end;
        }
    }

    if ((err = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, 0)) < 0) {
        Debug("Failed to write header to output file", err);
        goto end;
    }

    AVPacket videoPkt;
    int ts = 0;
    while (true) {
        if ((err = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &videoPkt)) < 0) {
            break;
        }
        videoPkt.stream_index = outVideoStream->index;
        videoPkt.pts = ts;
        videoPkt.dts = ts;
        videoPkt.duration = av_rescale_q(videoPkt.duration, inVideoStream->time_base, outVideoStream->time_base);
        ts += videoPkt.duration;
        videoPkt.pos = -1;

        if ((err = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &videoPkt)) < 0) {
            Debug("Failed to mux packet", err);
            av_packet_unref(&videoPkt);
            break;
        }
        av_packet_unref(&videoPkt);
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);

end:
    if (ifmt_ctx) {
        avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    }
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    }
    if (ofmt_ctx) {
        avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
    }
}
```

Header file:

```
#define VIDEOCAPTURE_API __declspec(dllexport)

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavcodec/avfft.h>

#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>

#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfiltergraph.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>

#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>

    // libav resample

#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>
#include <libavutil/file.h>


    // hwaccel
#include "libavcodec/vdpau.h"
#include "libavutil/hwcontext.h"
#include "libavutil/hwcontext_vdpau.h"

    // lib swresample

#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

    std::ofstream logFile;

    void Log(std::string str) {
        logFile.open("Logs.txt", std::ofstream::app);
        logFile.write(str.c_str(), str.size());
        logFile.close();
    }

    typedef void(*FuncPtr)(const char *);
    FuncPtr ExtDebug;
    char errbuf[32];

    void Debug(std::string str, int err) {
        Log(str + " " + std::to_string(err));
        if (err < 0) {
            av_strerror(err, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
            str += errbuf;
        }
        Log(str);
        ExtDebug(str.c_str());
    }

    void avlog_cb(void *, int level, const char * fmt, va_list vargs) {
        static char message[8192];
        vsnprintf_s(message, sizeof(message), fmt, vargs);
        Log(message);
    }

    class VideoCapture {
    public:

        VideoCapture() {
            oformat = NULL;
            ofctx = NULL;
            videoStream = NULL;
            videoFrame = NULL;
            swsCtx = NULL;
            frameCounter = 0;

            // Initialize libavcodec
            av_register_all();
            av_log_set_callback(avlog_cb);
        }

        ~VideoCapture() {
            Free();
        }

        void Init(int width, int height, int fpsrate, int bitrate);

        void AddFrame(uint8_t *data);

        void Finish();

    private:

        AVOutputFormat *oformat;
        AVFormatContext *ofctx;

        AVStream *videoStream;
        AVFrame *videoFrame;

        AVCodec *codec;
        AVCodecContext *cctx;

        SwsContext *swsCtx;

        int frameCounter;

        int fps;

        void Free();

        void Remux();
    };

    VIDEOCAPTURE_API VideoCapture* Init(int width, int height, int fps, int bitrate) {
        VideoCapture *vc = new VideoCapture();
        vc->Init(width, height, fps, bitrate);
        return vc;
    };

    VIDEOCAPTURE_API void AddFrame(uint8_t *data, VideoCapture *vc) {
        vc->AddFrame(data);
    }

    VIDEOCAPTURE_API void Finish(VideoCapture *vc) {
        vc->Finish();
    }

    VIDEOCAPTURE_API void SetDebug(FuncPtr fp) {
        ExtDebug = fp;
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you please make the header file available as well?

Comment: @ar2015 added header file

Comment: Hi @DmytroDovzhenko . Can you please help me with how I can merge two videos to create one video using code(C++). Both input videos playing side by side?

Comment: how to specify h265 instead of h264 when using av_guess_format ?

Comment: also, what's the purpose of remuxing at the end?

Comment: Excellent example! but if my input data in GRAY8-format (bmp origin) and I want to save them in GRAY8 too, in output stream? avformat_alloc_output_context2 - get's YUV420...  by default

Comment: Reiterating the question. What's the purpose of the remux?

Comment: Good answer because it gets the wheels going but see the solution provided by @BillYan

Answer (score 4):

```
if (fctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
    cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
//avcodec_parameters_from_context(st->codecpar, cctx); //cut this line

av_dump_format(fctx, 0, filename, 1);

//OPEN FILE + WRITE HEADER
if (avcodec_open2(cctx, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
    cout << "Error avcodec_open2()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
}

avcodec_parameters_from_context(st->codecpar, cctx); //move to here

if (!(fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
    if (avio_open(&fctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        cout << "Error avio_open()" << endl; system("pause"); exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this solution for a very long time thank you.

Comment: me too. I read this over and over and didn't realize the change (set parameters *after* opening the codec context. Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem (error 0xc00d36c4). This topic and replies helped me to solve my problem. The solution was adding just this code:

```
if (ofctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
```

Comment: this is very weird, because my problem was solved after removing this line (notice also in the original question, the author also had the above, but it didn't work)... I debugged the dumped packets. With the above, there is a missing header in the first frame. Removing the above solved the issue for me.

Comment: Can you tell in more details? If I remove the following code, Windows Media Player cannot play created MP4 video:

if (ofctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) {
        cctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}

Comment: you can check out my answer below to see why I reached this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the codec context extradata and extradata_size fields.

Comment: Documentation says "encoding: Set/allocated/freed by libavcodec."
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/structAVCodecContext.html#abe964316aaaa61967b012efdcced79c4
What should I put there?

Comment: I tried to extract extradata from generated .h264 and set it for mp4 container. Now video can be played, but it has 7k fps instead of 50, and 60 mb/s bitrate instead of 400kb/s. As a result, video length is 3ms (of 4 seconds original).