# how to fix Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; when using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

When I use `ffmpeg` to convert `m3u8` to `mp4`, I get some warning,

```
ffmpeg -i xx.m3u8 -c copy demo.mp4
```

warning is

```
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3277744, current: 3276712; changing to 3277745. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3277745, current: 3277736; changing to 3277746. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: U want to copy hls stream to mp4 file?

Comment: copy *.ts to mp4 file

Comment: is it single ts file?

Comment: If it is single ts file try it :: ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i *.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a copy demo.mp4

Comment: not a single ts file.

Comment: This could happen when you try to join to videos with different frame rates

Answer (score 11):

You can try this:

```
ffmpeg -i xx.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc demo.mp4
```

Per [this forum post](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/390057-FFMpeg-non-monotonous-DTS-in-output-stream-error#post2527823), you can also try:

> It seems that decoding time stamps are broken. You can try "-fflags
> +igndts" to regenerate DTS based on PTS:

Or point to the `.ts` file directly, ignore the DTS:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i xx.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -c:v copy -c:a copy demo.mp4
```

Comment: thank you , 
but also get 
"

Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1;

"

Comment: can u please share me hls ts format and is it nested m3u8 file?

Comment: "regenerate DTS based on PTS"? What do those abreviations mean?

Comment: "Decoding Time Stamp (DTS) and Presentation Time Stamp (PTS)" according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044330/

Comment: This answer appears to quote https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/390057-FFMpeg-non-monotonous-DTS-in-output-stream-error#post2527823

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this downloading sports video from HUDL. The m3u8 file had #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY and #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME directives that ffmpeg didn't handle correctly. So I just created .txt file for ffmpeg to simply concatenate the segments with the directives removed:

Find m3u8 using browser tools

```
cat ~/Downloads/<m3_u8 downloaded> | grep ".ts$" | awk '{print "file <url path of m3u8 file>" $1}' > files.txt

ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,tcp,http,https,tls -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -q 0 -c copy video.MTS
```

Comment: It seems that ffmpeg 4.4.x and 5.1.x support those streams correctly, also if there is nothing about that in the changleog.